# Use form data in Knockout URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have a resource called StaffContribution which records how many hours a member of Staff will contribute to a specific Activity.

My Web Api action for creating a new StaffContribution is: People/{StaffID}/Activities/{ActivityID}/StaffContributions

I have an MVC client with an Activity details page which displays all of the StaffContributions and allows other Staff to be added via Knockout. It contains the following form:

```
<form id="addStaffContribution" data-bind="submit: create">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Contributor</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StaffID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hours)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hours)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hours)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the following Knockout VM:

```
function StaffContributionsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.staffContributions = ko.observableArray();

    // This is what I need to fill in. ActivityID is in the ViewBag, StaffID is supplied in the form.
    var PostUrl='People/{StaffID}/Activities/{ActivityID}/StaffContributions'; 

    self.create = function (formElement) {
        $(formElement).validate();
        if ($(formElement).valid()) {
            $.post(PostUrl, $(formElement).serialize(), null, "json")
                .done(function (newContribution) { self.staffContributions.push(newContribution); });
        }
    }
    //... Put, Delete etc here.
}
```

What I need to be able to do is construct the PostUrl using the ViewBag.ActivityID and the StaffID supplied by the user in the form. I previously had this working by including the StaffID in the DTO rather than the URL but I feel it makes more sense that the StaffID be part of the URL as a StaffContribution is essentially a join table between Staff and Activity.

Can someone please show me how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
var PostUrl = 'People/@(ViewBag.StaffID)/Activities/@(ViewBag.ActivityID)/StaffContributions';
```

However, you'd want to move this variable out of your view model and namespace it properly so you don't get collisions in the global scope. You'll need to keep this bit of JS inline, but then the rest of your code can go into an external file.

Also, please don't confuse Knockout with jQuery. `$.post` is a jQuery method. It has nothing to do with Knockout.

UPDATE

There's a ton of different ways to handle this, just pick one. Probably the most efficient is to simply save `ViewBag.ActivityID` to a JS variable, and then later construct the URL inside the create method:

```
MyNamespace.ActivityID = '@ViewBag.ActivityID';

...

self.create = function (formElement) {
    var PostUrl = 'People/' + formElement.val() + '/Activities/' + MyNamespace.ActivityID + '/StaffContributions'

    $(formElement).validate();
    if ($(formElement).valid()) {
        $.post(PostUrl, $(formElement).serialize(), null, "json")
            .done(function (newContribution) { self.staffContributions.push(newContribution); });
    }
}
```

Comment: StaffID is not in the ViewBag. I need to be able to pull it from the formElement object which is a parameter of the create function. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Thanks for that. formElement.StaffID.value is successfully pulling the StaffID from the form.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just to this:

```
<input type="hidden" val="@model.StaffID" id="staff-id" />
```

...

```
var staffId = parseInt($('#staff-id').val(), 10);
```

then just append it in your string.

---

Or even just like `$('#addStaffContribution').find('input[type=hidden]').val()` and you could keep the MVC bindings